# Application pool user is a member of termstore administrator

Tags: term-store

Hi i want to run a user as administrator to create terms.

```
 SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
        {
            using (SPSite secureSite = new SPSite(site.ID))
            {
                TaxonomySession ts = new TaxonomySession(secureSite);
                TermStore termStore = ts.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"];
                Group group = termStore.Groups["MyGroup"];

                TermSet termSet = group.CreateTermSet("Termset");

                termSet.CreateTerm("Term", 1033);

                termStore.CommitAll();

            }
```

I can only create terms if the current user are a Contributor in the termstore, but i want to run this user as administrator without adding the user to the contributor in the term store?

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is not working is that TaxonomySession uses the user from the HttpContext. I found this [link](https://www.1stquad.com/sharepoint-kompetenz-erfahrung-know-how/blog/default/mai-2013/zugriff-mit-elevated-privilegs-auf-termstore) which is in German but the suggested code looks like this:

```
var siteId = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
HttpContext oldContext = null;
try
{
   //Save actual context and null
   oldContext = HttpContext.Current;
   HttpContext.Current = null;
   SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
   {
      using (var elevatedSite = new SPSite(siteID))
      {
         var taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(elevatedSite);
         var termStore = taxonomySession.DefaultKeywordsTermStore;

         //put your logic here

         termStore.CommitAll();
      }
  });
}
finally
{
   HttpContext.Current = oldContext;
}
```

Comment: Something went wrong
An unexpected error has occurred.

Page Maintenance Web parts: If you have sufficient privileges , you can use this page to temporarily close Web Parts or remove personal settings. Contact the Web site administrator if you want more information . @Andreas

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code? I pasted it into my VM first and it worked, although I didn't add anything to the TermStore.

Comment: SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site; get object reference not set?

Comment: If SPContext.Current is null this is not related to this issue. Are you working in the context of a webpart?

Comment: on button click in a webpart

Comment: But when i am not using httpcontext Spsite does not get null?

Comment: If you save site.ID before you set the HttpContext to null this sounds strange. I can't double check again right now, maybe in 1 or 2 hours from now.

Comment: it works not i need to add spsite in the top

Comment: I edited my code suggestion, please check.